# WildFly10 - unable to deploy my ears

Tags: deployment, jboss7.x, wildfly-10

Unable to deploy my ears into WildFly10.0.0 and same ear working fine in JBoss7.1.1 server. Here are the details of my project and error which i'm facing while adding my ear to server. Jar file used in ejbModule to prepare ear file attached as a screen shot. Giving an exception while adding it to server. same ear working fine in JBoss7.1.1 Final version.

```
**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**
 <jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
   <dependencies>
    <module name="com.hway.blz.fm" export="true"/>
    <module name="com.hway.blz.common" export="true"/>
    <module name="com.blazesoft" export="true"/>
    <module name="com.thoughtworks" export="true"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.ws.cxf.jbossws-cxf-client" services="true"  export="true"/>
     </dependencies>
     </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**fm-web.jar**:
Jar having two classes to expose my object model as wsdl using RPC\soap binding
\fm-web\ejbModule\com\hway\blz\fm\Fmbean.java

```
     [Error details provided in the attached screen shot][1] Pls. help me on this issue resolution.
Dismiss
Wed Apr 19 21:51:18 GMT-500 2017
Unable to assign fm-rules.ear. 
Unexpected HTTP response: 500 
Request
{
    "operation" => "composite",
    "address" => undefined,
    "steps" => [{
        "operation" => "add",
        "address" => [
            ("server-group" => "main-server-group"),
            ("deployment" => "fm-rules.ear")
        ],
        "runtime-name" => "fm-rules.ear",
        "enabled" => true
    }]
} 
Response
Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "result" => {"step-1" => {
        "outcome" => "failed",
        "rolled-back" => true
    }},
    "failure-description" => {"WFLYDC0074: Operation failed or was rolled back on all servers. Server failures:" => {"server-group" => {"main-server-group" => {"host" => {"master" => {
        "server-one" => {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
            "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.fm-rules.ear\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.fm-rules.ear\".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.fm-rules.ear:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.hway.blz.fm:main",
            "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.fm-rules.ear.fm-web.jar\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.fm-rules.ear.fm-web.jar\".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.fm-rules.ear.fm-web.jar:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.hway.blz.fm:main"
        }}}},
        "server-two" => {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
            "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.fm-rules.ear.fm-web.jar\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.fm-rules.ear.fm-web.jar\".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.fm-rules.ear.fm-web.jar:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.hway.blz.fm:main",
            "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.fm-rules.ear\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.fm-rules.ear\".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.fm-rules.ear:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.hway.blz.fm:main"
        }}}}
    }}}}}}



 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEP0O.png   
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9WHi.png
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a module `Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.hway.blz.fm:main`. You'll need to make sure that module is installed in the `$JBOSS_HOME/modules` directory.

Comment: its works for me after adding my relative jars under modules, Thank you James